# Using boost-beast to download a file give poor performance due to short sliding window

Tags: c++, boost, boost-beast

I'm using boost-beast connection on macOS application to download a file.. in some rare cases I see bad TCP performance. Packet trace investigation revealed that the TCP sliding window is very small (2688 bytes), about 2 packets, and I believe this cause the slowness, since if I use curl the window is much bigger (about 4MBytes).

I check the connection using `nettop` and saw different congestion method in each of the cases. Boost-beast connection used `ledbat` congestion whereas curl used `cubic` method.

I wonder if it can explain the difference in window size. Perhaps there's a way to set the congestion control method when opening boost-beast https connection ?

If we can obtain the underlying native socket from the connection, we can surely set this by using setsockopt. This however, give socket object and not the native one.

`boost::beast::get_lowest_layer(stream_).socket()`

Perhaps anyone can show me how to extract the socket and change its attributes using setsockopt ?

Comment: Get the native handle with `native_handle`.